# How to set route precedence with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

More specifically:

I have route myapp/about

And another route myapp/:userid

How do i ensure that ui-router always matches /about before /:userId ?

Comment: I think simply adding the "about" route before the `userId` route will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a state for this two `myapp/about` will will have one state called `about` & other will have accepting `userId` parameter.

```
.state('about',{
  url: '/myapp/about',
  templateUrl: 'appp/views/about.html',
  controller: 'aboutController'
})

.state('userDetails',{
  url: '/myapp/:userid',
  templateUrl: 'appp/views/userDetails.html'
  controller: 'userDetailsController'
})
```

By defining them as different state [**ui-router**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) will call the `about` statestate only when `/myapp/about` URL appears in browser, when URL other that `/myapp/about` appears in browser then it will call `userDetails` state that will accept `userid` which would be part after `/myapp/` you will get that parameter value using `$stateParams` service.

For making it more better you could add regex on route that will only ask for number or you can set any regx there, suppose I only want to accept number with 3 digits then I will change my `url` option of my state to `url: "/myapp/{userid:[0-9]{1,3}}"`, By giving this URL in state it will load the state only if the state has number with 3 digits like `123`,`111`,etc.